# Unable to restart, stop or start Solr server

Tags: solr

I reindexed my documents, and ran into a java out of memory java heap error. I tried to fix this by by adding `SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms5g -Xmx5g"` in my solr.in.sh file. Now I need to restart Solr for these changes to appear, but this happens in the command line:

```
 - $ bin/solr.cmd restart -p 8983 
 - find: ‘:0 ’: No such file or directory    find: ‘TCP ’: No such file
   or directory find: ‘:8983 ’: No such file    or directory No Solr
   found running on port 8983 find: ‘:0 ’: No such    file or directory
   find: ‘TCP ’: No such file or directory find:    ‘:8983 ’: No such
   file or directory The process cannot access the    file because it is
   being used by another process. Waiting up to 30 to    see Solr
   running on port 8983 Started Solr server on port 8983. Happy searching!
```

It acts like Solr is not running on port 8983, but it clearly is for me. Then in my Solr admin ui page, it still says- Xms512m-Xmx512m under JVM args section. So I feel like Solr is not even restarting. How can I restart Solr so that the changes I made to java heap appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @MatsLindh said was correct, and I solved this by going to the solr.cmd file and adding the line of code: `set PATH=%WINDIR%\System32;%PATH%;` under the line `@echo off`

Answer (score 2):

The `cmd` version of the script can't be ran under a bash shell in Windows. Use the regular `bin/solr` in that case. The error message is caused by `find` being a separate command in `cmd` in Windows, but when you run it through `bash`, it invokes the `find` unix command instead.